# How to find the department with the most employees in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00937

I am trying to find the department with the most employees in the demo HR schema:

```
SELECT d.DEPARTMENT_ID, d.DEPARTMENT_NAME, MAX(COUNT(e.EMPLOYEE_ID))
FROM departments d INNER JOIN employees e ON d.DEPARTMENT_ID = e.DEPARTMENT_ID
GROUP BY d.DEPARTMENT_ID, d.DEPARTMENT_NAME
```

The script works without `MAX()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your current query (minus the `MAX`) and select the department group with the largest head count.

```
WITH CTE (DEPARTMENT_ID, DEPARTMENT_NAME, empCount) AS
(
    SELECT d.DEPARTMENT_ID, d.DEPARTMENT_NAME, COUNT(e.EMPLOYEE_ID) AS empCount
    FROM departments d INNER JOIN employees e ON d.DEPARTMENT_ID = e.DEPARTMENT_ID
    GROUP BY d.DEPARTMENT_ID, d.DEPARTMENT_NAME
)
SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID, DEPARTMENT_NAME
FROM CTE
WHERE empCount = (SELECT MAX(t.empCount) FROM CTE t)
```

Comment: There is no `LIMIT` keyword in Oracle.

Comment: @BobJarvis I thought that he had tagged with MySQL.  In any case, my first answer stands and should work on Oracle.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It is syntactically incorrect. You need to add a group by to the outer query as well. Because, you are using MAX as aggregate. Else, it will throw `ORA-00937: not a single-group group function`

Answer (score 1):

You can try fetching the departments with order by desc on count(e.EMPLOYEE_ID) and using the ROWNUM by limiting the results only to the first row as below :

```
select * from (select d.DEPARTMENT_ID, d.DEPARTMENT_NAME, count(e.EMPLOYEE_ID) cnt 
from departments d inner join employees e on d.DEPARTMENT_ID = e.DEPARTMENT_ID 
group by d.DEPARTMENT_ID, d.DEPARTMENT_NAME order by 3 desc) where ROWNUM=1
```

Frankly, I couldn't test this query against Oracle DB as I only have Derby DB installed on my machine and this doesn't support ROWNUM psuedo-column.

Answer (score 1):

Please find the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT d.DEPARTMENT_ID, d.DEPARTMENT_NAME ,COUNT(e.EMPLOYEE_ID) EMP_COUNT
FROM HR.departments d
INNER JOIN HR.employees e
ON d.DEPARTMENT_ID = e.DEPARTMENT_ID
GROUP BY d.DEPARTMENT_ID, d.DEPARTMENT_NAME
ORDER BY EMP_COUNT DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `ORDER BY` clause like

```
select d.DEPARTMENT_ID, d.DEPARTMENT_NAME, 
count(e.EMPLOYEE_ID) as employe_count
from departments d
inner join employees e
on d.DEPARTMENT_ID = e.DEPARTMENT_ID
group by d.DEPARTMENT_ID, d.DEPARTMENT_NAME
order by count(e.EMPLOYEE_ID) desc
offset 0 rows fetch next 1 rows only;
```

Note: `OFFSET` and `FETCH NEXT` are only available starting with `Oracle 12.1`

Comment: Note that `OFFSET` and `FETCH NEXT` are only available starting with Oracle 12.1.

Comment: @BobJarvis, Yes, mentioned that in answer. See edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use  the **COUNT() OVER()** analytic function.

For example, using the standard `employees` table in `HR` schema:

```
SQL> SELECT DISTINCT department_id,
  2    COUNT(department_id) OVER(PARTITION BY department_id) rn
  3  FROM hr.employees t
  4  ORDER BY rn DESC;

DEPARTMENT_ID         RN
------------- ----------
           50         45
           80         34
           30          6
          100          6
           60          5
           90          3
           20          2
          110          2
           10          1
           40          1
           70          1
                       0

12 rows selected.

SQL>
```

To find the `department_id` with **maximum employees** from above result set:

```
SQL> SELECT department_id
  2  FROM
  3    (SELECT department_id,
  4      row_number() OVER(ORDER BY rn DESC) rn
  5    FROM
  6      ( SELECT DISTINCT department_id,
  7        COUNT(department_id) OVER(PARTITION BY department_id) rn
  8      FROM hr.employees t
  9      )
 10    )
 11  WHERE rn = 1;

DEPARTMENT_ID
-------------
           50

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select dname,deptno,loc from dept where deptno=(select deptno from 
(select deptno,count(*) as emp_count from emp group by deptno order by emp_count desc) where rownum=1)
```